# ignore root element in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to parse an xml file using JAXB.
My problem is that I need to skip the root node, If I delete it from the xml file I get what I need, otherwise - I get an empty object.

I'll give a simplified xml and my code (It behaves the same way):

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
<!--  <Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Office.xsd">
-->
    <Office>
        <Employees>
            <Employee>
                <name>George</name>
                <rank>3</rank>
            </Employee>
            <Employee>
                <name>Michael</name>
                <rank>5</rank>
            </Employee>
            <Employee>
                <name>Jeff</name>
                <rank>1</rank>
            </Employee>
            <Employee>
                <name>Todd</name>
                <rank>7</rank>
            </Employee>
            <Employee>
                <name>Jessica</name>
                <rank>5</rank>
            </Employee>
        </Employees>
    </Office>
</Root>
```

Office class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.Vector;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Office {

   @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Employees")
   @XmlElement(name = "Employee")
   private Vector<Employee> employees;

}
```

Employee class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee {

   @XmlElement(name="name")
   private String name; 
   @XmlElement(name="rank")
   private int rank;


   public void promote() {
      rank++;
   }

}
```

Driver:

```
import javax.xml.stream.*; 
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

import java.io.FileReader;
public class Driver {

     public static void main (String[] args) {
        parseOffice();

     }

     public static void parseOffice() {
        try {

          XMLInputFactory f = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
          XMLStreamReader reader = f.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("Office.xml"));

            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Office.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            Office office = unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader, Office.class).getValue();

            Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
          marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
          marshaller.marshal(office, System.out);

         } 
         catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: I omitted output because the post is long enough and it can be easily replicated; however If there's a need for me to include it, I'll do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parse the XML with a StAX `XMLStreamReader`, then advance it to the element you want to unmarshal, and then unmarshal it.

I posted a full example that should help on the related question linked below:

- [How to unmarshall SOAP response using JAXB if namespace declaration is on SOAP envelope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465653/how-to-unmarshall-soap-response-using-jaxb-if-namespace-declaration-is-on-soap-e/11467459#11467459)

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you create a generic root element?

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Root" ...)
public class Root {
   @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
   private Object content;
}
```

Add it to your context and unmarshal. You should get a `JAXBElement<Office>` as `content`.

Comment: Well, obviously I can do that - but that's not what I want Reason: I want to know how to do it without adding anything, if possible. I need a way to ignore or skip the root element. I guess, I should have mentioned it in my question. +1

Comment: @Michael You'll have to add something in any case. Either an additional root element mapping or the skipping code on the lower level. I'd say an extra root class is better as it's the same abstraction level as other mappings and woould work with anything (SAX, StAX, DOM). However you may have technical reasons (not transparent to me at the moment) to want to have it otherwise. Then do it on the lower level - skip StAX states, filter SAX events, pre-dive in the DOM.

Comment: Out of curiousity, how would I convert the `content` object to an office object? I could do it as Panther suggested, but is there an easy way to convert in a more generic fashion?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the root class in hierarcy. And get Office class from Root class.

Root Class:-

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.Vector;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {


 @XmlElement(name = "Office")
 private Office office; 
 }
```

Office class

```
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
 import java.util.Vector;


  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  public class Office {

  @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Employees")
  @XmlElement(name = "Employee")
  private Vector<Employee> employees;

  }
```

Change in parse method :-

```
       JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        Root root = unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader, Root.class).getValue();
        Office office = root.getOffice();
```

Comment: You limit the content to `Office` in the `Root` which isn't flexible.

Comment: @lexicore Thanks for input , i was just trying to solve his problem. As he doesn't seems to want to do much changes

Comment: No problem, was just a hint. Adn you're right, both of our anwers seem to be not suitable for the OP. This happens.